# Is it possible to change to Emacs input mode with Doom Emacs?

Tags: config

It's default input mode is vim. Didn't find the toggle option like Spacemacs with `M-m t E`.

https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vi` emulation of Doom is provided by `evil-mode` (see [Section *"Feature Highlights"* of readme.md](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs#feature-highlights)).

The [Evil Manual](https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#modes-and-states) says in Section 1.2 *"Modes and states"* that you can toggle between Normal state (vi-emulation) and Emacs state (normal keybindings) with the key sequence <kbd>C-z</kbd>.

Meanwhile I've tested it with Emacs 26.1 and Doom version 2.0.9.
<kbd>C-z</kbd> runs the command [`evil-emacs-state`](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/297b8f323754d967beeaed28080311f5afbe25c8/evil-states.el#L894-L899) which switches to Emacs mode. But one has to activate it buffer-wise.

If you want to activate Emacs state by default you can customize the variable `evil-default-state` to `emacs`.

The key binding <kbd>C-z</kbd> is a bit strange though since in Vanilla Emacs <kbd>C-z</kbd> is used for `suspend-frame`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Another question, do you know how to start terminal within it? I tried `SPC o t`, returned undefined.

Comment: @02040402 hlissner suggests `M-x term` in [issue 40](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/40) of doom-emacs.

Comment: Thank you! That's should exit terminal and kill buffer to quit.